# Get Object Model including it's contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently using

```
$('#myElement').prop('outerHTML')
```

to receive it's Object Model as a string.

The problem is, when I use

```
$('#myElement').prop('outerHTML')
```

I can only get the attributes of the Element (like class, id, styles,...). When it comes to h3 tag or p tag, the string I received has to 'content' at all.

Is there a way in jQuery or Javascript that I can receive the Object Model with both it's attributes and contents? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

This script will done your job. Please follow::

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myElement").wrap('</p>').parent().html(); // For getting full element as string
    $("#myElement").attr('YOUR_ATTR'); // For getting any attribute of that elemnt
});
</script>
```

Comment: typo `.atrr > .attr`

Comment: @ramabarca Thanx ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.attr()` function on main node `$('#myElement')`. See this once http://api.jquery.com/attr/